# How can I access the repository if don't have entity for that name Doctrine2  Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the bundle which is called the Linked Bundle. Now I have put all the mix stuff in there which is used across all bundles.

But I don't have any entity called Linked.

I want to create LinkedRepository so that i can have my all common function there. But how will i get that repository in other bundles. I mean how to call this

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('LinkedBundle:"*What should I write here*"');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a separate repository class. A repository class is linked to an entity, so you cannot have a "standalone" repository but I can see two options:

1. Subclass EntityRepository and name it LinkedRepository, here you can add your common methods. All your custom Repository class will have to subclass your LinkedRepository class. If you want that common functionality in all your Entity's Repository instances but you don't need a custom Repository class you can declare the LinkedRepository class as the Entity's repositoryClass `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\LinkedBundle\Repository\LinkedRepository")` assuming you have your Repository classes in the Repository folder inside your Bundle and replace Acme with your company name.
2. Create a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and add your common functionality in there.

I guess the first one is easier.

Answer (score 1):

i think this it is not possible as you intend to to it. But I would recommend using a Service Container instead of a Repository. In this Service Container you can use different repositories, which you need to use for these global tasks. The Service Container is also accessible in every controller etc..

Here is the Documentatino for it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
I don't think that you need the whole injection part. Just define an Service:

```
services:
    linked_service:
        class: Acme\LinkedBundleBundle\Service\LinkedService
```

And then get the service in your controller via

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $service = $this->get('linked_service');
}
```

Hope this works.